# Как решить проблему flex сетки вида sidebar content, когда содержимое content имеет запредельную ширину?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar {
  min-width: 220px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
}

.table {
width: 100%
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
height: 300px;
background: lime;
}

.table-content {
 width: 3000px;
 height: 300px;
 background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не понятно, что нужно с этим делать? Если ширина 3000px, а разрешение экрана 1920px, как вы хотите впихнуть невпихуемое?

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи ожидается, что .table с свойствами overflow скроет данные добавив скролл.

Answer (score 0):

Воть

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar {
  min-width: 220px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  width: calc(100% - 220px);
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
}

.table {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.table-content {
   width: 3000px;
   height: 300px;
   background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```